# Creating random string of characters only in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have searched through posts and the shortest and easiest I could find was

```
CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())
```

However, this as expected creates an alphanumeric string . `Translate` is available in Oracle but I am working on SQL Server and nothing of the kind is available in here. I however wanted a string that has characters only.

Can I please get some directions on this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What sort of random output are you expecting? How much entropy do you require?

Comment: If pseudo randomness is all you need, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152204/tsql-pseudo-random-text-generator

Comment: @YannickMeeus: That answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an "ugly" evolution of your code, but it works

```
DECLARE @NewId nvarchar(45)
set @NewId = newid()

SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@NewId, 1, 'A'), 2, 'B'), 3, 'C'), 4, 'D'), 5, 'E'), 6, 'F'), 7, 'G'), 8, 'H'), 9, 'I'), 0, 'L'), '-', 'M')
```